# JavaScript function not working inside angularjs function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to run JavaScript function inside angular function but i am facing error
(ever indexof, search function are not working)

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm input_high" name="groupname" id="groupname" ng-model="tech_groupname">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Dedicated-1">Test1</option>
                    <option value="Dedicated-2">Test2</option>
                    <option value="Yellow-2">Test3</option>
  </select>

<div class="ui-widget" ng-if="checkCorpPackage(tech_groupname)" ></div>

appTechInfo.controller('tech_info_ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope)
  { 
   //** check if package is corporate and need if start
    $scope.checkCorpPackage = function(temp_grp_name){
        //value is printed here if javascript function is not used
        console.log(temp_grp_name);

         //i have tested by getting data via scope too
        var test_data = $scope.tech_groupname;

        console.log(temp_grp_name.toLowerCase());
        /**
        if(temp_grp_name.indexof("Dedicated") > -1)
        {

           return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
         **/                  
    }
    //** check if package is corporate and need if start
  }]);
```

Error log
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

i have searched similar problems but solution they are providing is not working for me

Comment: That simply means `temp_grp_name` is `undefined`, i.e. nothing is passed to the function. How is the function called from view?

Comment: i have passed it when i call the function and i am getting the value on my console

Comment: Try checking why temp_grp_name is undefined.

Comment: i have added every thing on my code above it is value passed from select tag

Comment: I have added everything i have tried, is there any issue with the version

Comment: always always always use object in `ng-model`. Your problem is not having default value set on varible or checking if it is defined before user changes select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

temp_grp_name will be undefined because its value will be changed on change of select control. So you will have to handle it by checking undefined or null.and **indexof** will be **indexOf** as below

```
temp_grp_name.indexOf("Dedicated")
```

Comment: Thanks @Nimesh you addressed the problem i used indexOf instead of indexof (O must be capital )